# How to overlap image tag as a background over two CSS Grid areas

Tags: css, css-grid

The image is an img tag and needs to be stretched as a background image over two areas 'img' and 'content'. The text has to go above the stretched image in the 'content' area. Simple but how? I can't find any obvious answers online.

```css
.media {
    border: 2px solid #f76707;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff4e6;
    width: 100%
}
.media {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "img content";
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.image {
    grid-area: img;
    background-color: #ffd8a8;
}

.text {
    grid-area: content;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
    <img class="image" src="https://loremflickr.com/500/200" />
    <div class="text">This is a media object example. 
      We can use grid-template-areas to switch around the image and text part of the media object.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your code as follows:

```css
.media {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  width: 100%
}

.media {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "img content";
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.image {
  grid-area: img;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
}

.text {
  grid-area: content;
  padding: 10px;
}

.media {
  background-image: url("https://loremflickr.com/700/200");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
  <div class="text">This is a media object example. We can use grid-template-areas to switch around the image and text part of the media object.
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: The drawback here is the actual size of the image is now always clipped by `height: 150px;` and you cannot right-click on the image to save it to the desktop or something alike. So if downloading images should be made easy for the user keep the `IMG` tag.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to get the desired result.

You could also make the image a background of the `DIV` rather than having an `IMG` tag inside the `DIV`.

But I sticked to your code below and just added `CSS` to place the text `DIV` on top of the image and stretch the image to `100%` with hidden `overflow`.

```css
.media {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  width: 100% display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "img content";
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  grid-area: img;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.text {
  grid-area: content;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
  <img class="image" src="https://loremflickr.com/500/200" />
  <div class="text"><b>This is a media object example. 
      We can use grid-template-areas to switch around the image and text part of the media object.</b>   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So this way the bounding orange border will adjust to the height of the image. However loading the image has a short delay and therefore the orange border first shows as a line. If your images have a fixed height, you can set this height in px inside `.media { }`

Answer (score 2):

I think, if there is just one part of the page at the background of the page, you should create a style. Then look at the backgammon tag select whatever you want,Later, the ID will have it in created anything on the page, for example
Panel, td, div,.... get it there.
You do not need to add any image.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried position: absolute on the text div?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out if anyone stumbles across it: (make sure you preview with full page)

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 100px;
  grid-template-areas: "empty text" "mobile mobile";
}

#container img {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container p {
  grid-area: text;
  color: red;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #container p {
    grid-area: mobile;
    color: red;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/500/200">
  <p>SOME TEXT OVER IMAGE</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `<p>SOME TEXT OVER IMAGE</p>` is not over the image!